# Does `pip install` add current directory to PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, pip

If I have a python project that contains a `setup.py` file I can run `pip install --user -e .`. This will install all of the requirements listed in the setup file and add the current project to my pip list:

```
$ pip show project-name                                                                                
Name: project-name                                                                                    
Version: 1.0.0                                                                             
Summary: None                                                                                                                             
Location: /path-to-project/                    
Requires: matplotlib, numpy, scipy, ...                                                    
Required-by:
```

Will this by default add the `\path-to-project\` to the users PYTHONPATH, or do you have to do that manually, so you can import the code via `import project-name` from any location on the system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `pip` does not alter the `PYTHONPATH` and you don't need to either. `pip` instead uses standard paths set by Python when you install the project. You don't need to make any changes, you already installed the package in a standard location when you ran `pip install --user`.

Projects installed with `-e` use an *egg link* file and are added to a `.pth` file in a standard location. The location shown is listed in a `project-name.egg-link` file (really just a piece of metadata to track packages) and the same path is added  to the `easy-install.pth` file in the same directory. Python automatically adds any paths listed in `.pth` files to the module search path on startup (this is handled by the [`site` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html)).

The same set of standard paths is also used to find the project again when you run `pip show`; that the command works shows that the project is *already* on the Python module search path, correctly installed.

You can verify the paths by running `python -m site`. Because you installed the package with the `--user` switch, the location `pip` uses is shown there as the `USER_SITE` path. Check that path to find the `*.egg-link` and `easy-install.pth` files.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer, I am not installing a package from PyPI using pip. I am installing a python project that contains a `setup.py`, so this will not install in site-packages for example, but instead to /path-to-project/ as shown in the `pip show` in my question. Will I then need to add  /path-to-project/ to my PYTHONPATH in order to import this project's code, or has pip done that automatically?

Comment: @jw1294: sorry, my answer wasn't as complete as it could have been. I've added additional pointers to show how `-e` projects are handled.

Comment: right that clears it up, so the egg file gets created in site-packages and that contains the location of the project?

Comment: @jw1294: yes, but that's not how Python then finds the project. That's how `pip` and other tools knows that the project was installed by a tool and not by some manual editing. The path is also added to a `.pth` file (`easy_install.pth` here) and *that file* is used to add additional paths to `sys.modules`.

Comment: @jw1294: so deleting the `.egg-link` file will not remove the project from the Python module search path, but editing `easy_install.pth` to remove the path will.