# How solve ImportError: No module named fcm_django error in python

Tags: python

When running `python manage.py runserver` get this error

```
ImportError: No module named fcm_django???
```

I run this command

```
pip install django-fcm  --process-dependency-links
```

this can't solve anything

how i solve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
pip install fcm-django
```

it will solve this error

Answer (score 0):

try `pip3 install fcm-django`

or check your python path!

Comment: Before mixing `pip` and `pip3` one should ask for necessary details instead of making suggestions into the blue. pip installs to standard paths that usually are in the PYTHONPATH   [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060587/803359). Please be so kind and modify your post accordingly